# How to read memory at pointer (local_tbb.dwData) to get window handle

Tags: javascript, winapi, firefox-addon, jsctypes

I've been lacking sleep so I'm just super over killing this one.

What I'm trying to do is get the handle from a window from a task bar button. Following this tutorial here: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/10497/A-tool-to-order-the-window-buttons-in-your-taskbar. This is the specific part:

> **Getting the window handle**
>
> This was the really lucky part. I thought to myself: "Where would I
>   keep the window handle?". They must keep it somewhere, to enable the
>   activation of the correct window when a button is selected. The
>   obvious place to keep it would be in a structure for each button, and
>   the obvious place to keep the pointer to this structure would be in
>   the dwData field of each TBBUTTON.
>
> So I had a look at the dwData fields, and they appeared to be
>   pointers. OK so far. Then I had a look at the memory they pointed to,
>   and there they were: the first field stores the window handle Smile |
>   :) )) Microsoft developers aren't so different, after all Smile | :)

So I successfully get the task bar button like this:

anyways this is how i get local_tbb:

```
remote_tbb = ralloc_alloc(struct_TBButton.size);
var rez = SendMessage(hToolbar, TB_GETBUTTON, i, ctypes.voidptr_t(remote_tbb));
if (!rez) { throw new Error('Failed on SendMessage of TB_GETBUTTON'); }

var local_tbb = new struct_TBButton();
var retRead = ralloc_read(remote_tbb, local_tbb.address());
var freed = ralloc_free(remote_tbb);
console.log('freed', freed);

for (var n in local_tbb) {
    console.log(n, local_tbb[n]);
    try {
        console.log('toString', n, local_tbb[n].toString());
    } catch (ignore) {}
}
```

and succesfully get the `dwData` field populated. From this `console.log` is when it does it on `dwData`:

```
"dwData" UInt64 {  }
"toString" "dwData" "1499288"
```

So now I want to do what that guy said and `Then I had a look at the memory they pointed to`. So I'm trying to do that.

So I know I have to do something like this, but what IPC command should go into the `SendMessage` (currently I'm using `0x004A /** WM_COPYDATA **/` but this can't be right) and where should I put in the `local_tbb.dwData` as address?

```
    var remote_hwnd = ralloc_alloc(ctypes.voidptr_t.size);
    var smHwndRez = SendMessage(hToolbar, 0x004A /** WM_COPYDATA **/, local_tbb.idCommand, ctypes.voidptr_t(remote_hwnd));
    console.log('smHwndRez=', smHwndRez);

    var local_hwnd = ctypes.voidptr_t;
    var retRead = ralloc_read(remote_hwnd, local_hwnd.address());
    console.log('retRead=', retRead);

    var freed = ralloc_free(remote_hwnd);
    console.log('freed=', freed);

    console.log('local_hwnd = ', local_hwnd, local_hwnd.toString(), uneval(local_hwnd));
```

Comment: You really need to be more specific in your questions, and post re-producible, minimal code examples. People are in the process of closing this question because "Unclear what you're asking", and I can't say I blame them. While I *think* I understand your question, but that is only the case because I read your other questions before (and I don't like guessing, anyway). Please re-write your question so that people can actually understand it (e.g. you should mention that you're using `WINAPI` from Firefox js-ctypes, so regular `WINAPI` folks don't get confused, and WTF is `ralloc_alloc`, etc.)

Comment: Ah ok I'll work on that now. This is my code that can run in scratchpad (copy/paste) but it's hard to make minimal of it that can be reproduced. :( [GitHubGist :: _ff-addon-snippet-GetHandleFromTBB](https://gist.github.com/Noitidart/1fc56b28be82d45a245d) I commented out the get handle part because its so bad the comment out starts on line 238.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Strictly speaking, this is not `winapi`, as this is not part of the API but undocumented implementation details.

From what I can gather:

- Get the `TBBUTTON` data.
- The `.dwData` contains a pointer to multiple(?) `HANDLE`s (`voidptr_t`s)
- So reinterpret `.dwData` as a `voidptr_t`, i.e. `new ctypes.voidptr_t(.dwData);`
- use `ReadProcessMemory` to read another pointer from the location `.dwData` points to. That is (supposed to be) your window handle.

So something like this:

```
var tbb = new TBButton();
...
var dataPtr = new ctypes.voidptr_t(tbb.dwData);
var handle = new ctypes.voidptr_t();
// Important: pass the address of |handle|, not |handle| itself.
if (!ReadProcessMemory(process, dataPtr, handle.address(), ctypes.voidptr_t.size, null)) {
  throw new Error("Failed to read window handle");
}
```

Comment: Oh my gosh thank you so much. It worked perfectly! Do we have to use `new` in front of `ctypes.voidptr_t(`? I never do I'm just wondering if i should change. Here is the copy pastable code [GitHubGist :: Noitidart / _ff-addon-snippet-GetHandleFromTBB](https://gist.github.com/Noitidart/1fc56b28be82d45a245d). I'll still work on editing the topic post, thanks so much nmaier man.